# Google Maps Javascript API - StreetView Disable Keyboard/Mouse Rotate and Keyboard Zoom

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-street-view

How can I execute actions specified in the title.

I tried on this basis, but could not:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would rotate via the mouse, but for the keyboard-shortcuts it works for me when I observe the keydown-event of the `<body/>` and stop the propagation of the event when one of the particular keys has been pressed:

```
 //run this after the page has been loaded
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.body,'keydown',function(e){
    if([37,38,39,40,107,109,187,189].indexOf(e.keyCode)>-1){   
      e.stopPropagation();return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is good to the keyboard problem, thank's!

Comment: Can I use this solution of the map div container or just only use this to the full document?

Comment: for me it didn't work when I  add the listener to the div.

Comment: Unfortunately, I experienced the same thing. :(

Comment: Can I define the className or ID to the StreetViewPanorama DIV?

Comment: it's a simple DOMNode, you may assign each valid attribute

Comment: Find somewhere about a list?

Comment: Alas this solution does not work for me. If I add `console.log(e)` I can see the events are caught by the handler but StreetView still rotates and zooms. In fact, even if I click-focus a text input the panorama still seems to grab +/- and (un)happily zooms, tho other keys don't seem to get propagated. I tried many things including adding `preventDefault()` to the handler but to no avail.

Comment: Even worse it seems that the keyboard controls aren't even DOM events?? If I remove all events using `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).forEach(function(el) {evl=getEventListeners(el);Object.keys(evl).forEach((ev)=>evl[ev].forEach((e)=>(e.remove())))})` (chromium), no clicks or drags work anymore but StreetView keyboard navigation persists!!!

Comment: Further removing listeners from `document` with `evl=getEventListeners(document);Object.keys(evl).forEach((ev)=>evl[ev].forEach((e)=>(e.remove()))) ` does disable keyboard navigation but still not the zoom.

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately